# using json typescript, export a typed object

Tags: json, typescript, typescript-typings

I want to export a typed object, of a json, to avoid using `any` as a type. But Im not sure how to create the d.ts file and use it in my project. My json uses platform, brand, locale, environment. This is what i have tried so far.

myjson.json

```
"desktop": {
    "brandname": {
        "eu": {
            "a": "www.url.com",
            "b": "www.otherurl.com",

        }
    }
}
```

myjson.d.ts

```
export class EnvUrlMap {
  environment: string;
}
export class LocaleEnvMap {
  locale: EnvUrlMap;
}
export class BrandLocaleMap {
  brand: LocaleEnvMap;
}

export class PlatformBrandMap {
  "desktop": BrandLocaleMap;
  "mobile": BrandLocaleMap;
}

export {PlatformBrandMap as map};
```

index.ts

```
import map = require('my.json');
export {map};
```

---

PROJECT

main.ts

```
import { map } from 'my-project';

const config = (map as Map);  `- ?? what is the type here ? Error cannot find Map`
```